# why I search in map stl time difference is a lot?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

When I use a `std::map`, it seems that accessing elements takes a different amount of time based on the method used.

First Method: Direct Access

```
cnt += umap[t];
```

Second Method:

```
if (umap.find(t) != umap.end()){
    cnt += umap[t];
}
```

The second method seems to be quite a bit faster than the first method, and I don't understand why. Can someone explain the differences between these two methods?

Comment: how did you measure the time? How did you compile the code? Optimizations turned on? What compiler and what flags did you use? why do you think it would be a problem when one is faster than the other?

Comment: Can we get a [mre] of this benchmark?  Depending on the data set and what you are doing, there may or may not be a difference.

Comment: `umap[t]` creates new entry if entry doesn't exists with default value. With `if` check you are preventing from creating new item.

Comment: Note that the 2 snippets are doing different things. The first one can increase the map size, which will definitely have a performance difference.

Comment: even faster: `if(auto it = umap.find(t); it != umap.end()) cnt += it->second;`

Comment: (I guarantee at least one person will discover [`if`'s init-statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) from the above comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the code snippets is doing a different thing.

The first snippet takes more time because it inserts a key `t` to `umap`, if it does not exist (and initializes it with zero), before adding it to `cnt`.

In second snippet no key is inserted. Because of the `if` condition, `umap[t]` is (called then) added to `cnt` only when `umap` has the key `t`.

The second snippet can be more optimized by temporarily storing the iterator returned by `find`. In second snippet, `operator[]` internally calls `find` method again, which in turn increases time complexity.

Hence, an attempt like this will prove much faster (picked up from [user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/user253751)'s comment):

```cpp
if(auto it = umap.find(t); it != umap.end())
    cnt += it->second;
```